# Как расставить запятые

Tags: пунктуация

Как расставить запятые:
Ну как там в Москве?

Comment: Не надо ничего ставить. Руки чешутся, что ли?

Answer (score 1):

Если "там" частица, то запятая не требуется: "Ну как там в Москве"?
Если "там" наречие, то запятая требуется, потому что "в Москве" будет уточнением, где именно "там": "Ну как там, в Москве?"